# Ctrl key randomly stop working

Tags: 20.04, dell

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on my laptop randomly stops working. Is not clear to me, how to make it work again, since sometimes just pressing <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> will make it work, sometimes I press the right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> a few times and the left start working, and other times I have to wait. Is a very random but frequent issue.

I run a dell diagnostic in the bios and the keyboard seems to be fine. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> never had any issues while running the diagnostic tool multiple times.

This is occurring in a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.02 on a Dell XSP 13 9300.

**Edit**

Both left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> stop working and start working at the same time, which seems to me to be an indicator that is not an hardware issue. Also, I tried several solutions, in particular:

1. Disable pointer location in google-tweaks
2. Remove all the languages except one at the Regional settings
3. Select Ibus as input method
4. Reconfigure keyboard configuration
5. Make sure that the <kbd>capslock</kbd> is off

One extra point, this issue is not happening on an external keyboard(at least I was not able to replicate it in ~an hour of usage).

Comment: sometimes CAPS can be a problem, (in my Linux - when I have CAPSLOCK on, I can't e.g ctrl + p to paste, I must turn it off first)

Comment: I would start by trying another keyboard, you never said you did that.

Comment: @WilliamMartens I don't have the CAPSLOCK on. The issue does not happen on an external keyboard.

Comment: @joaonrb Okay,  - worth mentioning;  thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix this issue following the instructions at https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/issues/7664

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: This didn't work for me and I can't get any of the Ctr keys to work at the moment.